# PDF creation with the capability to use filter on different PDF files

Tags: xml, database, pdf, pdf-generation

I need your help with an idea came to my mind.

I have bunch of PDF files which are tests in my colleage. I want to create a new PDF file which contains one exercise from each PDF (and if possible by using a filter word to determine which exericse to  choose).

The issue is that I want this process to be automated. That is, by a click of a button, bunch of exercies from different PDF files will be filtered into a new PDF file and will be saved somewhere in the disk.

Following are the questions about the idea:

1. Is there any freeware available to do this?
2. If I want to implement it by myself how can I create a database which allows me to save and extract PDF content with its original look and feel (margins and so on).

Thank you very much!

Comment: How can a software recognize the end of one exercise and the start of a new one in your source PDFs?

Comment: Each exercise starts with the word "Exercise" and then its number. For example : "Exercise #1" and then "Exercise #2" and so on...

Comment: 1.) Does the PDF contain the information for text extraction? (You can test by trying to copy&paste from Adobe Reader.) If not, finding the word may be difficult. 2.) Is guaranteed that that word does not appear as part of an exercise? If not, the criterion must be more elaborate. 3.) When an exercise does not start at the top of a page, do you want that exercise in the new PDF to be re-flowed and start at the top? If yes, that's making things more difficult, re-flowing PDFs can be difficult, especially in case of embedded images. 4.) I doubt that a ready-to-use freeware solution exists.

Comment: 1.) Yes ( I can copy&paste the text from Adobe Reader). 2.)Yes It is guaranteed - the word only appear on the top of each exercise. 3.) I don't care about the flowing of the text. 4.) So do you have any suggestion how can I implement this idea by my own?

Comment: Are you comfortable with Java? I could give some hints which require the use of a PDF library, and I'm mostly at home with Java and libraries available for Java...

Comment: unfortunately not, but if you have general guidance it might help me. I know c++, XSLT (XML transformation) and C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can use iTextSharp or PdfSharp to implement a solution, assuming each exercise starts on a new page. 
Loop through the document's pages and search the current page for the word 'Exercise'. If the word is found, create a new empty document, extract the page from the source file and insert it in the new document. Search the next page, if the 'Exercise' word is found, save the previous document and create a new one. If the word is not found, extract the page and insert in the document you already created. 
In this way you can implement any filtering you want.